# error accessing new \integral command, I think it is due to syntax

Tags: math-mode, section-titles, scalerel

error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. ...ac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{e^{x^2}}}}{\theta}$}
```

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mismath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\newcommand{\simbolo}{\displaystyle\intup}
\newcommand{\integral}[2]{\stretchrel[300]{\simbolo}{#1\di #2}}

\begin{document}
    
\section{$\integral{\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{e^{x^2}}}}{\theta}$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use that humongous symbol also in moving arguments, use `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mismath}
\usepackage{stix2}

\newcommand{\simbolo}{\displaystyle\intup}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\integral}[2]{\stretchrel[300]{\simbolo}{#1\di #2}}

\begin{document}

\section{$\integral{\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{e^{x^2}}}}{\theta}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You shouldn't use it anywhere, less so in titles. Just say no.

Comment: you should add a table of contents, for extra loveliness